# Nested cross-validation with GroupKFold with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

In my data, several entries correspond to a single subject and I don't won't to mix those entries between the train and the test set. For this reason, I looked at the `GroupKFold` fold iterator, that according to the `sklearn` documentation is a *"K-fold iterator variant with non-overlapping groups."*
Therefore, I would like to implement nested cross-validation using `GroupKFold` to split test and train set.

I started from the template given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996995/use-groupkfold-in-nested-cross-validation-using-sklearn). However, I got into an error calling the `fit` method on the grid instance saying that `groups` has not the same shape of `X` and the `y`. To solve that, I sliced `groups` too using the train index.

Is this implementation correct? I mostly care about not mixing data from the same groups between train and test set.

```py
inner_cv = GroupKFold(n_splits=inner_fold)
outer_cv = GroupKFold(n_splits=out_fold)


for train_index, test_index in outer_cv.split(x, y, groups=groups):
    x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model,
                                param_distributions=parameters_grid,
                                cv=inner_cv,
                                scoring=get_scoring(),
                                refit='roc_auc_scorer',
                                return_train_score=True,
                                verbose=1,
                                n_jobs=jobs)
    grid.fit(x_train, y_train, groups=groups[train_index])
    prediction = grid.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: The question you linked seems incorrect. It's a javascript question.

Comment: Thanks @bernie, I've fixed the link

Answer (score 2):

One way you can confirm that the code is doing as you intend (i.e. not mixing data between groups) is that you can pass not the `GroupKFold` object but the output (the indices) of `GroupKFold.split` to RandomizedSearchCV. e.g.

```
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model,
                            param_distributions=parameters_grid,
                            cv=inner_cv.split(
                              x_train, y_train, groups=groups[train_index]),
                            scoring=get_scoring(),
                            refit='roc_auc_scorer',
                            return_train_score=True,
                            verbose=1,
                            n_jobs=jobs)
grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I believe this leads to the same fitting result, and here you've explicitly given the indices of training/validation for each fold of the cross-validation.

As far as I can see, these two ways of doing it are equivalent, but I think the way your example is written is more elegant since you aren't providing `x_train` and `y_train` twice.

And it appears correct to slice `groups` using `train_index`, since you're only passing the sliced `x` and `y` variables to the `fit` method. I have to remind myself that the inner cross-validation will be doing cross-validation on the training subset of the outer cross-validation operation.