# How to split data into train and test using groupby column

Tags: python, dataframe, train-test-split

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks something like this:
The following table is an example, I have like 120000 questions 
 
Question | Hint | Cluster Label|

q1   |q1_h1 |1

q1   |q1_h2 |1

q1   |q1_h3 |1

q2   |q2_h1 |2

q2   |q2_h2 |2

q3   |q3_h1 |1

q4   |q4_h1 |2

q4   |q4_h2 |2

I want to groupby question and split dataframe into train and test such that associated question and hints are captured together and stratified on label.
So output that I require would be:

train:

Question | Hint | Cluster Label|

q1   |q1_h1 |1

q1   |q1_h2 |1

q1   |q1_h3 |1

q2   |q2_h1 |2

q2   |q2_h2 |2

test:
Question | Hint | Cluster Label|
q3   |q3_h1 |1

q4   |q4_h1 |2

q4   |q4_h2 |2

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split the DataFrame according to the value in `Hint`:

```
df_train= df[(df['Hint'].str.contains('q1')) | (df['Hint'].str.contains('q2'))]
```

and similarly for df_test

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but the above table is an example, I have like 120000 questions

Comment: Then you need to explain how you want the split to take place ie. define split condition(s) and maybe provide an example split which is an adequate representation of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `GroupKFold` or `StratifiedGroupKFold`.

From the [user manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#group-k-fold), `GroupKFold` "is a variation of k-fold which ensures that the same group is not represented in both testing and training sets."

To use it, you call the constructor as normal:

```
gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits = 5)
```

and when you call the `split` method of `gkf` you specify the variable to group on (in your case 'Question').

If you're using it in `GridSearchCV` or similar, you specify the group in as the 'groups' variable in the call to `GridSearchCV`. [See previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67235442/14278409).